# Adapt a* pathfinding algorithm to a very large map with many different sections

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, optimization, path-finding

I looked into HPA*. The issue is that large parts of my map will be either empty or very sparsely obstructed, and some parts are very densely obstructed.

I also don't like how units must walk through transition points between clusters, because that looks very unrealistic. This wont matter much for very dense areas but for open ones they should just walk in a straight line to the target.

Right now 100 units can traverse an empty 100x100 grid in 5ms, using a*. However, my maps will be probably 10,000 x 10,000.

To be more specific:

I am looking for a way to use HPA*, but only in dense areas. And in areas with sparse obstacles, just walk in a straight line (and around obstacles). I would also like the unit to be able to path find from a sparse area to a dense or vice versa if they require separate algorthhms.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would try modifying HPA* so that, instead of finding a path through the waypoints around its current cluster, the unit would find a path through the waypoints around the edge of the 9x9 subgrid of clusters *centered* on its current cluster.

As the unit moves, the 9x9 subgrid will move *before* the unit gets to one of the waypoints around the edge.  It will then find a path using the new waypoints that are farther away, and will never actually have to walk through a waypoint.